# memtester exit code 6

Tags: ram, memtest

In Ubuntu 18.04 I have been running `memtester` to test the RAM of the hardware. Upon using the command

```
sudo memtester 100M 2
```

I get an exit code

```
6
```

which is not documented in the man page. What does an eit code of `6` mean then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the memtester man page:

```
memtester's exit code is 0 when everything works properly. Otherwise, it is the logical OR of the following values:

x01
    error allocating or locking memory, or invocation error 
x02
    error during stuck address test 
x04
    error during one of the other tests
```

So a 6 is a logical "OR" of a 2 and a 4